# AJAX help needed

Tags: ajax, list

i have problem in ajax.. im new comer for ajax...:)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#bcode").focus();
    //prevents autocomplete in some browsers
    $("#bcode").attr('autocomplete', 'off').keyup(function(event)
    {
        var name = $("#bcode").val();



            $("#status").empty();
            if(name.length > 17 )
            {
                selectAll();

                $("#status").html('<img align="absmiddle" src="loading.gif" /> Checking availability...').show();
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "namecheck.php",
                data: "bcode="+ name,
                success: function(msg)
                {
                    $("#status").html(msg).show();
                }
                });

        }
        else
        {
            $("#status").html('').addClass('err').show();
        }
    });
});

//-->

</script>
```

i got text box value 'bcode' using '$_POST['bcode']'

```
<input name="bcode" type="text" class="bcode" id="bcode" maxlength="18"; />
```

also i have menu/list in that form

```
<select name="pallete" class="list_box" id="select">
                <option value="P0" selected> </option>
              <option value="P1">P1</option>
              <option value="P2">P2</option>
              <option value="P3">P3</option>
              <option value="P4">P4</option>
              <option value="P5">P5</option>
</select>
```

How i can access selected item from php file by using  '$_POST['pallete']'

please help me.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You're not passing the "pallete" value in the post data. As it is, only the "bcode" value will be sent to the server. Is your question related with this or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

The same way you've retrieve the value for 'bcode' and stored it into a variable to pass through on the AJAX call, you should do another for 'pallete' and append it on the AJAX call.  See below:

var pall = $("#pallete").val();

data = "bcode=" + name + "&pallete=" + pall;

Comment: it also produces output 'undefined'  ...,  
please give me a complete code , 

i have textbox name='bcode' and menu/list name='pallete'


how i can access values using $_POST['bcode']; and $_POST['pallete'];

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You are sending only the bcode text box value with post. With that you can send other data also.

Try this,

```
var name = $("#bcode").val();
var selectedVal=$("#pallete .selected").val();

     $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "namecheck.php",
                    data:  { bcode: name, SelectedVal: selectedVal },
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        $("#status").html(msg).show();
                    }
                    });
```

Comment: oh... it produces output 'undefined'  ... 
please give me a complete code 

i have textbox name='bcode' and menu/list name='pallete'
thanks..

how i can access values using $_POST['bcode']; and $_POST['pallete'];

Comment: You have to use $_POST['SelectedVal']; at server side to get data.